# Meteor debugger not working properly

Tags: node.js, debugging, meteor, node-inspector

I couldn't find any working tutorial for debugging meteor on server side.
Running `meteor debug` gives `localhost:8080/debug?port=5959` but it's useless. When I put debugger in server code it stops after 10-20s (it's faster to put console.log). Also if I use `SomeCollection.find()` it just doesn't work - I wait, and don't receive any result.

Is there any working example of how to debug it, because I must admit that debugging with `console.log` is very frustrating?

Comment: The server side debugger normally works quite well. I usually put a `debugger` statement near where I'm having a problem and the debugger will stop there so I can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Well in my case it does not work well - I put a `debugger` statement in my server code, but first it stops after a while (10-20s), and every command takes some time to return result (ie. if I want to check value of `var foo;` i write `foo`, hit enter and result shows also after a while). When I want to get some data from mongo (ie. `Collection.find().count()`) it's just does nothing - I even went to my kitchen to make a tea, came back and still not result. It is still faster to put console.log in code - which you can guess can be pain in the "us".

Comment: Sorry I don't have better advice and agree that console.log() is pretty pedestrian. Not sure what kind of machine you're running on. I'm on a 16MB MBP, Chrome. Debugging speed for server code is not an issue there.

Comment: I'm on MacBookPro wth 8GB ram and i5 on board - speed of machine is not an issue here. I run NVM, so maybe it has something to do with that (OSX or NVM)